# Go - is it possible to encrypt excel workbook

Tags: excel, go, encryption

I have checked the [excelize](https://godoc.org/github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize#File.ProtectSheet) package, there's the `ProtectSheet` function. However this only protects the sheet from changes etc not protecting from the unauthorised access.

I have look for several other options/packages and they don't seem to offer such capabilities.

I know that ultimately I could still zip-password protect the excel file, but being able to protect the workbook itself is much preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Go language Excelize library support encrypt workbook with password since v2.6.1. Reference the issue, [#199](https://github.com/xuri/excelize/issues/199), you can specify password like this:

```
workbook.SaveAs("Encryption.xlsx", excelize.Options{Password: "your_password"})
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research it seems there's no Go packages that can achieve this. However I've come across a npm package - [secure-spreadsheet](https://github.com/ankane/secure-spreadsheet) that is able to password protect an excel file.

As I needed to program the password protect operation in Go, what i did was to trigger an os command in the Go code to invoke the npm package to password protect the file.

The Go program is deployed & executed in an alpine container, which i can install the `node-npm` and have access to `npx` command.

code sample:

```
func passProtectExcelWorkbook(filename, outFilename string) error {
    passwd := "password"
    cat := exec.Command("cat", filename)
    excel := exec.Command("npx", "secure-spreadsheet", "--password", passwd, "--input-format", excelExt)

    file, err := os.Create(outFilename)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error when creating excel file: %v err: %v", outFilename, err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    excel.Stdin, err = cat.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error when reading from cat command output: %v", err)
    }

    excel.Stdout = file

    if err := excel.Start(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error when starting npx command: %v", err)
    }

    if err := cat.Run(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error when running cat command: %v", err)
    }

    return excel.Wait()
}
```